# Setting up VPN so that web application can securely stream audio files

Tags: php, mysql, vpn, openvpn, rackspace

We have a web application (php) that retrieves audio via a local ip using flash (path to file gotten from mySQL). This is ok, but we can't access the files unless we're on the local network (clearly). Now we also need to set up a similar solution in a remote office which obviously our current set up won't work.

The main goal is to be able to navigate to our hosted (Rackspace) web application, and have it be able to communicate with audio servers in 2 remote locations (here and the remote office).

We're looking at VPN (OpenVPN) solutions but they seem complicated and potentially overkill (although very secure). How can we securely access audio from our web app and be able to stream it with flash? Any detail information I can provide. Just not sure what kind of info is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could open an SSH proxy to the remote server from the local box like so:

```
ssh -ND 9999 user@host.com
```

Use that as a SOCKS proxy (and it's encrypted over SSH) on port 9999. Any request will pop out on the remote server.

If the web browser is streaming audio then you'll need the browser to request the file from the local server, which in turn fetches it from the remote server over the SOCKS proxy. This can be achieved with a PHP script. I can expand further if needed.

Hope that helps!

Comment: So what you're saying is create a proxy, query for it on the Rackspace server (which holds our web app) and the proxy will actually end up fetching it from the server we have here (or the other server we eventually will be setting up)?

Comment: been doing some research and ultimately a reverse proxy i think is the answer but this definitely helped!